# What is the meaning behind the titles of Tokyo Ghoul OVAs JACK & PINTO?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

For reference, the dictionary definition of the word "pinto" is

> Marked with spots of white and other colors; mottled; spotted.

It can also be used to refer to a piebald horse which has irregular patches of two colors such as this one:
[image: Piebald Horse]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that "Jack" is a reference to "Jack the Ripper" because in the OVA, the main characters are chasing a serial killer. It could also be a reference to "Jack-o'-lantern" since the serial killer wears a pumpkin mask and is referred to as "Lantern".
 On the other hand, the only two things I can come up with for Pinto is that it's a reference to (spoilers ahead): 
1

> The hidden bruises on the elderly patient which look like the spots of a piebald horse. The patient's skin was thus like a "pinto" horse.

2

> The dual personalities that the nurse had because "pinto" could mean the she had spots of white (good) and black (bad).

I think theory #1 on the elderly man is more likely to be right than the nurse theory.

Comment: Stop answering your own question for reputation.

Comment: @GKA there's nothing wrong with [self-answering](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), provided that the question and the answer have its own merit. Also, I was the one who suggested OP to put his theory as the answer because it is *one of the possible answer*, and so it can be voted accordingly. And there's nothing to stop anyone from providing a better/official answer to this question.

Comment: Oh.Thats weird.I did not know you could answer your own questions.Anyway thanks for telling me)

Comment: @GKA I originally posted my answer as part of the Question Description in a previous post but AkiTanaka explained that it made more sense to post my own theory as an answer so that the question could stand on its own. BTW, I did wait for others to answer before I posted my own answer. I also googled other theories but found nothing.